# Why is /f/ easier to pronounce than /p/?

Tags: phonology, proto-indo-european, proto-germanic

[[Source:]](http://qr.ae/RGTZTG) Assistant Professor of Linguistics [Andrew McKenzie](http://people.ku.edu/~a326m085/), University of Kansas

> In particular, there is no real reason *why* certain changes happen while others don't.  For instance, the *** *p*** sound from Proto-Indo-European became an *** *f*** sound in Proto-Germanic.  Eventually, this explains why Germanic words like English ***f***ather, ***f***ish, and ***f***oot correspond to Latin or Romance words like ***p***ater, ***p***isc-, and ***p***ed-.  `We know that in many languages, /p/ changes to /f/ because it's easier to pronounce.`  But we can't explain why /p/ changed to /f/ in Proto-Germanic and no other branch of Indo-European.  There is no why.

1. The title of my question concerns the sentence coloured in grey above. I already listened to audio clips of these IPA symbols [here](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/).

2. Which subfield of linguistics comprises questions like this? What are some good introductory books, written for the layperson? I'm guessing [historical linguistics and phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_linguistics#Phonology)?

Comment: I think your guess is a good one. The title of your question flips /p/ and /f/ around. However, questions of "ease" of pronunciation can be a little bit complicated. For Korean speakers, /p/ is easier to pronounce than /f/, because native Korean words have the former sound but not the latter.

Comment: @sumelic Thanks. I fixed my title. You wrote `your guess is a good one`, but what guess do you mean? Neither the Professor above, nor I, guessed anything?

Comment: "I'm guessing historical linguistics and phonology." I just meant that I agree with you that these are the relevant subfields of linguistics.

Comment: The scope of "We know that in many languages" in McKenzie's statement is not clear to me. Interpreting it the way I initially did, /f/ is easier to pronounce than /p/ only in some languages, not all. Many Indians don't have /f/ in their L1. If they borrow words from English that need the /f/ sound, they produce a /ph/ instead. Though they know they must pronunce it with an /f/, they find it hard to do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dHIlfCjlRk

Comment: In addition to @prash 's comment, many Armenians consider ֆ `[f]` is ruining the phonetic harmony of their language. ֆ is a Medieval adoption to the alphabet (originally dated 405 AD), primarily used for loanwords.

Comment: I agree with @user6726 below that ease of pronunciation is not relevant for historical sound change, but note that, if infant language acquisition is any indication, an argument could be made that the _reverse_ is true--that is, **[p] is easier to pronounce than [f]**. Labial stops (oral and nasal) are among the first sounds to be acquired, with the voiceless labiodental fricative [f] coming later on.

Comment: I wonder if this McKenzie is mistakenly thinking of 'lenition' as being equivalent to 'ease of pronunciation'?

Comment: My 4 year old kid pronounces "p" from almost day 0, but still can't get "f" right. If "f" was easier than "p", we'd have "fafa" across languages for "dad" instead of "papa".

Comment: I agree that [p] generally comes before [f] for infants (and languages like Armenian and Persian don't really have native [f]), but to be precise we should point out that it could be unvoiced or voiced, eg [b] (as in Arabic, where there is no [p]).

Comment: @carsten the Southern dialect of Vietnamese has [f] and [b] but no [p], and many people have problem pronouncing [p], so [f] and [b] are easier to pronounce than [p]

Comment: Conversely, Finnish doesn't have an [f] except for loan words.

Comment: Another thing to consider: which "p" and "f" are we talking about in the first place? A French or Dutch "p" may be misunderstood as a "b" by English speakers. Perhaps a French "p" is easier to pronounce than an English one.

Comment: @reinierpost same in Vietnamese [initial /p/ sound only appears in loanwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_phonology#Initial_consonants)

Answer (score 6):

It is simply false that "ease of pronunciation" is the reason behind sound changes, although this is a common misconception. In fact, nobody has ever devised a method of objectively quantifying the notion of articulatory difficulty. It is more likely that the change is a result of a chain of *perceptual* issues, reducing to the problem of distinguishing aspirated labial stops and fricatives.

A three-way study of this topic is necessary, involving phonology, phonetics, and historical linguistics. Historical linguistics can frame the initial question, based on remote relations like Indo-European * *p* to Germanic * *f*. Phonetic studies provide the concrete psychological and acoustic basis for speculating about why aspirated /tʰ/ might sound like [ts], and phonology provides the logical glue in terms of the discrete unit sounds of languages where one category changes to another category.

While we lack the factual information needed to explain why Grimm's Law affected Germanic and not Italic or Slavic, we can explain why GL could have happened in the history of Germanic (and other languages which acted likewise). However: this is not a layman's research topic, it requires a relatively advanced understanding of all three areas.

Comment: The "3-way study" you refer to above comes together nicely in work by Juliette Blevins, Andrew Garrett, and Pam (Patrice) Beddor, picking up the thread of research started by the incomparable John Ohala.
Blevins wrote a fantastic book, _Evolutionary Phonology_ outlining a theory of phonetic/phonological change. A thorough synposis is available here:
http://washo.uchicago.edu/seminar/Blevins2006_TL.pdf

Also, Mark Hale's book _Historical Linguistics: Theory and Method_ goes into some detail about how a mechanism like this could work. (Disclaimer: Mark was one of my MA advisors)